# How do I change the color of my snake's body to alternate from white to crimson?In pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm having trouble with make the snakes body alternate colors from white to red.

I made a new "new.segments" and it dose what I want but no the correct way. Doing this method adds two segments when picking up one fruit.

```
    # Add a segment
    new_segment = turtle.Turtle()
    new_segment.speed(0)
    new_segment.shape("circle")
    new_segment.color("white")
    new_segment.penup()
    segments.append(new_segment)
```

I want the snake to be able to pick up one fruit and be white then pick up a different fruit and then be red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to store the last added color somewhere, but, without seeing your entire code, another simple way is to check if the number of elements in your `segments` list is odd or even; something like this:

```
...
new_segment.color("red" if len(segments) % 2 else "white")
...
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out sloth